# How to obtain and/or save the queryset criteria to the DB?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I would like to save a queryset criteria to the DB for reuse.

So, if I have a queryset like:

```
Client.objects.filter(state='AL') 

# I'm simplifying the problem for readability. In reality I could have 
# a very complex queryset, with multiple filters, excludes and even Q() objects.
```

I would like to save to the DB not the results of the queryset (i.e. the individual client records that have a state field matching 'AL'); but the queryset itself (i.e. the criteria used in filtering the Client model).

The ultimate goal is to have a "saved filter" that can be read from the DB and used by multiple django applications.

At first I thought I could serialize the queryset and save that. But serializing a queryset actually executes the query - and then I end up with a static list of clients in Alabama at the time of serialization. I want the list to be dynamic (i.e. each time I read the queryset from the DB it should execute and retrieve the most current list of clients in Alabama).

---

Edit: Alternatively, is it possible to obtain a list of filters applied to a queryset?

Something like:

```
qs = Client.objects.filter(state='AL')
filters = qs.getFilters()
print filters

{ 'state': 'AL' }
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do as jcd says, storing the sql.

You can also store the conditions.

```
In [44]: q=Q( Q(content_type__model="User") | Q(content_type__model="Group"),content_type__app_label="auth")

In [45]: c={'name__startswith':'Can add'}

In [46]: Permission.objects.filter(q).filter(**c)
Out[46]: [<Permission: auth | group | Can add group>, <Permission: auth | user | Can add user>]

In [48]: q2=Q( Q(content_type__model="User") | Q(content_type__model="Group"),content_type__app_label="auth", name__startswith='Can add')

In [49]: Permission.objects.filter(q2)
Out[49]: [<Permission: auth | group | Can add group>, <Permission: auth | user | Can add user>]
```

In that example you see that the conditions are the objects `c` and `q` (although they can be joined in one object, `q2`). You can then serialize these objects and store them on the database as strings.

--edit--

If you need to have all the conditions on a single database record, you can store them in a dictionary

```
{'filter_conditions': (cond_1, cond_2, cond_3), 'exclude_conditions': (cond_4, cond_5)}
```

and then serialize the dictionary.

Answer (score 4):

You can store the sql generated by the query using the queryset's `_as_sql()` method.  The method takes a database connection as an argument, so you'd do:

```
from app.models import MyModel
from django.db import connection

qs = MyModel.filter(pk__gt=56, published_date__lt=datetime.now())
store_query(qs._as_sql(connection))
```

Comment: In recent Django, it's now .query().

Answer (score 4):

You can use http://github.com/denz/django-stored-queryset for that

Answer (score 3):

You can pickle the Query object (not the QuerySet):

```
>>> import pickle
>>> query = pickle.loads(s)     # Assuming 's' is the pickled string.
>>> qs = MyModel.objects.all()
>>> qs.query = query            # Restore the original 'query'.
```

Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#pickling-querysets

But: You can’t share pickles between versions

Answer (score 1):

you can create your own model to store your queries.
First field can contains fk to [ContentTypes](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/)
Second field can be just text field with your query etc.

And after that you can use [Q object](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) to set queryset for your model.

Comment: Would you like to elaborate on how that addresses the issue of getting a queryset criteria and storing it in the database and then recovering it from the database and executing it?

Answer (score 1):

The current answer was unclear to me as I don't have much experience with pickle. In 2022, I've found that turning a dict into JSON worked well. I'll show you what I did below. I believe pickling still works, so at the end I will show some more thoughts there.

### models.py - example database structure

```python
class Transaction(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=24, primary_key=True)
    date = models.DateField(null=False)
    amount = models.IntegerField(null=False)
    info = models.CharField()
    account = models.ForiegnKey(Account, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=False, default=None)

class Account(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    email = models.EmailField()

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True)

class Rule(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=False, null=True, default=None)
    criteria = models.JSONField(default=dict)  # this will hold our query
```

My models store financial transactions, the category the transaction fits into (e.g., salaried income, 1099 income, office expenses, labor expenses, etc...), and a rule to save a query to automatically categorize future transactions without having to remember the query every year when doing taxes.

I know, for example, that all my transactions with my consulting clients should be marked as 1099 income. So I want to create a rule for clients that will grab each monthly transaction and mark it as 1099 income.

### Making the query the old-fashioned way

```python
>>> from transactions.models import Category, Rule, Transaction
>>>
>>> client1_transactions = Transaction.objects.filter(account__name="Client One")
<QuerySet [<Transaction: Transaction object (1111111)>, <Transaction: Transaction object (1111112)>, <Transaction: Transaction object (1111113)...]>
>>> client1_transactions.count()
12
```

Twelve transactions, one for each month. Beautiful.

But how do we save this to the database?

### Save query to database in JSONField

We now have Django 4.0 and a bunch of support for [JSONField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#jsonfield).

I've been able to grab the filtering values out of a form POST request, then add them in view logic.

#### urls.py

```python
from transactions import views
app_name = "transactions"
urlpatterns = [
    path("categorize", views.categorize, name="categorize"),
    path("", views.list, name="list"),
]
```

#### transactions/list.html

```html
<form action="{% url 'transactions:categorize' %}" method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <label for="info">Info field contains...</label>
  <input id="info" type="text" name="info">
  <label for="account">Account name contains...</label>
  <input id="account" type="text" name="account">
  <label for="category">New category should be...</label>
  <input id="category" type="text" name="category">
  <button type="submit">Make a Rule</button>
</form>
```

#### views.py

```python
def categorize(request):
    # get POST data from our form
    info = request.POST.get("info", "")
    account = request.POST.get("account", "")
    category = request.POST.get("category", "")

    # set up query
    query = {}
    if info:
        query["info__icontains"] = info
    if account:
        query["account__name__icontains"] = account

    # update the database
    category_obj, _ = Category.objects.get_or_create(name=category)
    transactions = Transaction.objects.filter(**query).order_by("-date")
    Rule.objects.get_or_create(category=category_obj, criteria=query)
    transactions.update(category=category_obj)

    # render the template
    return render(
        request,
        "transactions/list.html",
        {
            "transactions": transactions.select_related("account"),
        },
    )
```

That's pretty much it!

My example here is a little contrived, so please forgive any errors.

### How to do it with pickle

I actually lied before. I have a little experience with pickle and I do like it, but I am not sure on how to save it to the database. My guess is that you'd then save the pickled string to a [BinaryField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#binaryfield).

Perhaps something like this:

```python
>>> # imports
>>> import pickle  # standard library
>>> from transactions.models import Category, Rule, Transaction  # my own stuff
>>>
>>> # create the query
>>> qs_to_save = Transaction.objects.filter(account__name="Client 1")
>>> qs_to_save.count()
12
>>>
>>> # create the pickle
>>> saved_pickle = pickle.dumps(qs_to_save.query)
>>> type(saved_pickle)
<class 'bytes'>
>>> 
>>> # save to database
>>> # make sure `criteria = models.BinaryField()` above in models.py
>>> # I'm unsure about this
>>> test_category, _ = Category.objects.get_or_create(name="Test Category")
>>> test_rule = Rule.objects.create(category=test_category, criteria=saved_pickle)
>>>
>>> # remake queryset at a later date
>>> new_qs = Transaction.objects.all()
>>> new_qs.query = pickle.loads(test_rule.criteria)
>>> new_qs.count()
12
```

### Going even further beyond

I found a way to make this all work with my htmx live search, allowing me to see the results of my query on the front end of my site before saving.

This answer is already too long, so here's a link to a post if you care about that: [Saving a Django Query to the Database](https://startcodingnow.com/save-a-django-query-to-database/).